# Input port declaration format

Tags: verilog

I found a verilog I2S module [here](https://github.com/skristiansson/i2s), and I am trying to understand it.

The module starts with the delaration
 `parameter AUDIO_DW   = 32` 
Then further down is the following:

```
input [AUDIO_DW-1:0]    left_chan,
input [AUDIO_DW-1:0]    right_chan
```

then

```
reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0]      bit_cnt;
reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0]      left;
reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0]      right;
```

I am still learning verilog, and my text, as well as tutorials online do not suggest this port declaration format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bus.  The parameter just gets substituted in.  So it's equivalent to saying something like:

```
input [31:0]    left_chan,
input [31:0]    right_chan

reg [31:0]      bit_cnt;
reg [31:0]      left;
reg [31:0]      right;
```

That is, you're declaring two 32-bit input buses, and three 32-bit registers.

Note that the parameter value can be over-ridden using defparam when the module is instantiated.